# Tomcat not serving files from maven-war-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to make my Tomcat server serve a file. I made a very simple example to show you what's wrong, and even if it's simple, it's not working.

My project is made like this:

```
test
|->assets
|   |->testB.txt
|->src
|  |->main
|  |  |->webapp
|  |  |  |->WEB-INF
|  |  |  |  |->web.xml
|  |  |  |->testA.txt
|-> pom.xml
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>assets/</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>
```

If I execute `mvn package tomcat6:run`, I can access `testA.txt` but I can't access `testB.txt`, even if, when I have a look a the ".war" generated, I see :

```
|->testA.txt
|->testB.txt
|->META-INF
|->WEB-INF
|  |->web.xml
|  |->classes
```

I can't figure out why I have access to one but I can't see the other (404 error) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `testB.txt` because when running `tomcat6:run`, the Tomcat Maven Plugin will look at the `webapp` folder by default, not at the generated war file (via the `package` phase) nor at the generated unpacked war in the `target` folder.

This is made on purpose so that you can create on the fly new resources or change their content and changes will be available on the running instance (hot deploy).

You can verify it by:

- Add an additional `testC.txt` to the war file, it will be ignored by the running instance
- Add an additional `testC.txt` to the built unpacked war, it will be ignored
- Add an additional `testC.txt` to the webapp folder, it will be available!

From its [official documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/deployment.html):

> The default location is ${basedir}/src/main/webapp

You can configure it via the `warSourceDirectory` element. In your case, you want to point it at the built unpacked war of the `target` folder. So you can change your configuration as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <warSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: it is now pointing at Maven built via the `package` phase. And it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware of that. It's working just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

`tomcat6:run` doesn't run the packaged war, try with `mvn tomcat6:run-war` instead.